# Jekyll variable site.static_files is null

Tags: jekyll

I have an ultra simple Jekyll site that builds without error and Jekyll variables seem to be populated as expected except `site.static_files` which is null, despite there being a bunch of static files.

[Here is a link to the source code](https://github.com/david-lennox/testJekyllStaticFiles/tree/gh-pages). And [here is a link to the output](http://david-lennox.github.io/testJekyllStaticFiles).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:

Github pages [uses Jekyll 1.5](https://pages.github.com/versions/) and static_files are only available since version 2.0.0 ([see history](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/history/#v2-0-0))

**Edit #2 08-24-14**

Github is currently at 2.2.0, so we can use `site.static_files`

Comment: One wonders if one could not ask GitHub to use a newer version.

Comment: When I need the newest version, I build locally and deploy the _site folder with a .nojekyll file.

Comment: So, as I decided to ask, I saw this https://github.com/github/pages-gem/pull/75 !! \0/

Comment: OK, that seems to be an answer to my question/comment. Thanks for looking. And \o/ indeed.

Comment: Thanks for this. Seems a bit silly not to mention that in the docs given that many come to Jekyll via GitHub.